# How to play video through FragmentTabHost in android

Tags: android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I made an application that has 4 tabs:

1. vedio tab, in this tab I want to play video, taking remote url
2. virtual lab
3. edit video
4. help

I have made MainActivity class in which use FragmentTabHost class id for display tab.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHostabove;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
        super.onCreate(arg0);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Vedio").setIndicator("Vedio",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),FragmentTab.class,null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Virtual Lab").setIndicator("Virtual Lab"),FragmentTab.class,null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Edit Vedio").setIndicator("Edit Vedio"),FragmentTab.class,null);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Help").setIndicator("Help1"),FragmentTab.class,null);
        mTabHostabove = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhostabove);
        mTabHostabove.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent);

        mTabHostabove.addTab(mTabHostabove.newTabSpec("Logo").setIndicator("Logo"),FragmentTab.class,null);
        mTabHostabove.addTab(mTabHostabove.newTabSpec("Vedio Url ").setIndicator("Vedio Url",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher)),FragmentTab.class,null);
    }
}
```

I have also made FragmentTab class which extends Fragment.

here is code:

```
public class FragmentTab extends Fragment {
    private TextView tv;
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
                tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
                mVideoView =  (VideoView)v.findViewById(R.id.vedioview);
                tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        String path1="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
                        MediaController  mc = new MediaController(getActivity());
                        mc.setAnchorView(mVideoView);
                        mc.setMediaPlayer(mVideoView);
                        mVideoView.setMediaController(mc);
                        mVideoView.requestFocus();
                        // mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +"/"+R.raw.song));
                        mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path1));
                        mc.show();
                        mVideoView.start();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }  
                }
            });
            String tag = this.getTag();

            if (tag == "Vedio") {
                tv.setText("play vedio");
            }
            if (tag == "Edit Vedio") {
                tv.setText("want to Edit Vedio !!!!!!!");
            }
            if (tag == "Help") {
                tv.setText("do u want help !!!!!!!");
            }

            if (tag == "Virtual Lab") {
                tv.setText("Enter Virtual lab !!!!!!!");
            }

            return v;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 
        }
    }
```

I am stuck with to play vedio on click vedio tab
anybody solve it if u can . I have searched for 3 days, but i have not found a solution. vedio sound is coming, but vedio is not playing.

Answer (score 0):

Not all devices support all video codecs.

I had the same problem: I work with mp4-format and a resolution of 1280x720. This video format wasn't support by all devices (e.g. HTC Wildfire S). After changing the resolution to 480x360 the video was shown by all devices.

This link should help you:
http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html